# Custom "POST" request to skip website login screen? 

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, forms, post

There's a certain website I need to access multiple times each day that requires me to enter my login name/password first, every time.  To save some time, I copied-and-pasted the HTML source code and pre-populated the text fields with my info, then saved that to my desktop.  Now I can just open that doc in my browser and click "submit" without having to type anything.

I'm wondering if I can go a step further.  Whatever data is sent when I click "submit" — I'd like to *start* with that step.

From what I understand, the form info is converted into a POST request and sent to the web server.  Is there some way I can concoct that request manually (without using their login screen) and then execute that request each time I need to access the site?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a way. In fact there are many ways depending on the programming language you using.

Comment: Nope, it's actually just a timekeeping site on my company's intranet.

Comment: @J.Steve: Since it's an internal app, I wonder if you can take it even further and write your own client interface for it.  That way you wouldn't need a browser at all, you'd just have a little virtual punch clock for keeping time.  If it's a commercial product, find out if it has an API.  If it's home-grown, the possibilities are wide open.

Answer (score 0):

wow, what a safe site! Anyhow yes you could do this lots of ways. Not a good idea to transmit tho locally. Have you ever just tried using one of the form auto forms plugins for FireFox? one button and it will populate your form for you.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this in an active browser because you want to be able to interact with the site after logging in, correct?

A really simple way to do this and end up with a workable browser might be to try using [WatiN](http://watin.org/).  The library itself is generally used to automated in-browser testing.  But at the hear of it, that's kind of what you're doing here.  You just want an executable that will open a browser, navigate to a page, populate a form, submit, and present the result.

This isn't so much from the perspective of crafting the POST request manually, but rather just automating the UI interaction.

Ultimately, though, it's going to be a matter of testing it for what your user experience is like.  Does it take longer than you want?  Does it leave the application running in the background unnecessarily?  etc.

Honestly, this might really be overkill.  Browsers have form auto-population these days.  Maybe a browser plugin to take advantage of that instead?  How transparent does it *need* to be?